# Why is "preconceive" wrong?

Tags: etymology

Spell checks always mark it as wrong, though its initial existence is pre + conceive; but it is always corrected to "preconceived." What about situations like this though?

> People preconceive (present form) that dogs bark when they're angry or furious only.

"Preconceived" is past tense. How do you use it correctly in the present form then?

Comment: Your spellcheck thinks that *preconceived* only exists as an adjective, like *undiscovered*. Spellcheck is [wrong](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/preconceive), even though *preconceived* is indeed almost always an adjective and not a verb.

Comment: No matter how good a spell-checker or grammar-checker you use, there are times when it will be wrong—not only because its dictionary is smaller than the better ones, but also because it is not aware of all the senses and usages of words, in all possible sentence constructions.  It will _flag as errors_ some things that are perfectly OK, and it will _fail to catch many mistakes_, especially in word usage. So don't depend too heavily on it. It's a good tool, so far as it goes, but as you see, it's not the final authority!    . . . +1 for your question.

Comment: Your spellcheck is inadequate: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/preconceive

Answer (score 2):

It may come down to usage. Because the word is rarely used, perhaps it is considered safer to warn you in case you have made a mistake. If you really want to use the word, you can easily add it to the dictionary.

[image]
[Google ngram: preconceive,conceive](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=preconceive%2Cpreconceived&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpreconceive%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpreconceived%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Among the citations there:' "Let us preconceive" is nonsense *per se*' (https://books.google.com/books?id=aHLsy1dG4noC&pg=PA112&dq=%22preconceive%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAWoVChMI46Gtz7b7xgIVB5-ACh10iQJg#v=onepage&q=%22preconceive%22&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

[This dictionary.com reference page has two quotes using preconcieve in the present tense:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/preconceive)

> It was impossible for Harold to preconceive the effect this had on Esther. (Felix Holt, The Radical - George Eliot)
>
> How little did I preconceive the conduct which, in an exigence like this, I should be prone to adopt. (Wieland; or The Transformation - Charles Brockden Brown)

Answer (score 0):

To preconceive is to conceive (or imagine) something before the event that reveals or confirms it. It is similar to "imagine beforehand". No-one in the year 1890 could preconceive the atom bomb.

Comment: In your example, you could just as well use _conceive_.

Comment: Yes, I could use "conceive" so as to make a valid sentence, but that would not give the sense that the idea eventually came true, which is what I hope to imply by using "preconceive".